# LifeCycleCallback are not fired when a Collection Field Changed (add or remove)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfony3.4, when I update an instance of Vente Entity, I have two cases:

- If I update at least a **Simple Field** like (date,int,string,etc...) => the Callback "**PreUpdateCallback**" is fired
- When I update only the **collection** $*elementsVente* by adding/removing/updating a row => the Callback "**PreUpdateCallback**" is not fired

So, What is the matter and is there a solution to fix this.

Thanks.

## Vente Entity

```
/**
 * Vente
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vente")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VenteRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Vente
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @Assert2\ElementVente()
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ElementVente", mappedBy="vente", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $elementsVente;

    //...

  /*
  * @ORM\PreUpdate
  */
 public function preUpdateCallback()
 {
     die('fired');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`PreUpdate` lifecycle event is [triggered](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/7319f524a39f08f9e97a71804b6d4329f7d79e92/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1151) by `UnitOfWork` component of Doctrine. As can be seen from code - it is triggered inside `executeUpdates` method that is responsible for updating single entities. Hence this event is mean to be used for entities themselves and not related to collection changes.

Comment: So, what will be the cleanest Solution to trig collection changes ?

Comment: The only possible way that I can see from Doctrine code is to listen for `onFlush` event and take computed collection changes from `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` and `getScheduledCollectionDeletions()` methods of `UnitOfWork`